# How to curl an IPv6 address of a forwarding rule in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-load-balancer

I have created a forwarding rule that forwards TCP traffic to the target instance:

```
gcloud compute forwarding-rules create forwarding-rule-1 \
  --load-balancing-scheme=EXTERNAL \
  --subnet=lb-subnet \
  --ip-version=IPV6 \
  --region=asia-east1 \
  --ip-protocol=TCP \
  --ports=80 \
  --target-instance=target-instance-1 \
  --target-instance-zone=asia-east1-a
```

I run the following command to get the IP address of the forwarding rule:

```
gcloud compute forwarding-rules describe forwarding-rule-1 \
 --region=asia-east1
```

The output is as follows:

```
IPAddress: 2600:1900:4030:c58:8000:3:0:0/96
IPProtocol: TCP
creationTimestamp: '2022-11-24T08:01:58.737-08:00'
description: ''
fingerprint: xxxx=
id: 'xxxxx'
ipVersion: IPV6
kind: compute#forwardingRule
labelFingerprint: xxxx
loadBalancingScheme: EXTERNAL
name: forwarding-rule-1
networkTier: PREMIUM
portRange: 80-80
```

Curl the IPv6 address:

```
curl 2600:1900:4030:c58:8000:3:0:0
```

This returns an error: `URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`

What am I missing here?

Comment: I'd suggest to do a better research next time, there are a lot of questions here showing how to do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41843247/how-to-curl-using-ipv6-address or even https://tech.bluesmoon.info/2011/12/using-curl-with-ipv6-addresses.html

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Ferregina. There are links that can help you with this concern. However to avoid confusion with other users when they search this question. Ill be posting @Ferregina comment as answer. You can use this [link](https://tech.bluesmoon.info/2011/12/using-curl-with-ipv6-addresses.html) to curl ipv6 and based from the link the sample command is `curl "http://\[2600:xxx:yyy::zzz\]/page.html"`

Another useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41843247/how-to-curl-using-ipv6-address) is came from the same platform which is here in stackoverflow.